Lambda not working trigger message from SQS FIFO, but it does from SQS Standard
i just created lambda function that have trigger from SQS FIFO, but somehow not working.
Already add the AWSLambdaSQSQueueExecutionRole and AmazonSQSFullAccess to the lambda, but seems not working.
Other than that, im trying with standard SQS, the message is showing on Cloudwatch and i think its working.
My question is:

does SQS FIFO trigger works with lambda? i just search trough internet, and i think it supported.
is there a missing step, or missing policy for FIFO?


Yes, it should work with a FIFO queue. Are you only sending one message to the queue, or are you sending many? Do any messages trigger the Lambda function, or are you saying that the Lambda function connected to the FIFO queue is never invoked? Please Edit your Question and tell us more about how you tested the queues/Lambda function.

After some research, yes it does work.
I forgot to put permission into lambda to access KMS
